# RewriteCond RequestURI why RegEx doesn't work?

Tags: mod-rewrite, regular-expressions

i have a working RewriteCond like:

RequestURL:
http://www.myserver.com/images/gallery/summer/2013/2013-07-07/thumbs/001.jpg

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/gallery/summer/2013/*
RewriteRule ^images/gallery/summer/(.*)$ http://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/$1 [P]
```

This works fine and the image is pulled from Amazon S3.

But why the heck a RegEx doesn't work in the RewriteCond like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images/gallery/summer/2013/(.*)$
```

It's just i want to understand why the above code works and the other doesn't?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

REQUEST_URI begins with /, so instead of this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^images/gallery/summer/2013/(.*)$
```

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/gallery/summer/2013/(.*)$
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Mike's answer is correct. Consider turning on the RewriteLog to observe what mod_rewrite is actually doing. This will give you much better insight into what your rules should actually look like.

Also, putting (.*)$ on the end of a RewriteCond is unnecessary and inefficient unless you're actually planning to use the value of %1 in a later RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

you should just remove ^ from your command.
**try this:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/gallery/summer/2013/(.*)$
```